# DRY in spec mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm coding some specs for a mailer which sends multiple emails.
The controller of the mailer is:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  if @message.valid?
    @message.email.each do |email|
      MessageMailer.new_message(@message, email).deliver
    end
    redirect_to users_index_path, :notice => "Email sent correctly"
  else
    notice = "There was an error"
    render :new
  end
end
```

and the spec:

```
describe "POST 'create' for a diffusion" do
  it "returns http success" do
    @diffusion = Fabricate.build(:diffusion)
    post 'create', message: @diffusion
    response.should be_success

    @before_send = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    @diffusion.email.each do |email|
      MessageMailer.new_message(@diffusion, email).deliver
    end
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size.should eq @before_send + @diffusion.email.size
  end
end
```

The issue is when I create a Post request, for some reason it doesn't send emails, so I have to force it.

Is there any way to force to send the emails when I create a post request? Is it mandatory to repeat myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you capture `@before_send` before posting to `create`.

```
describe "POST 'create' for a diffusion" do
  it "returns http success" do
    @diffusion = Fabricate.build(:diffusion)
    @before_send = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size

    post 'create', message: @diffusion
    response.should be_success

    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size.should eq @before_send + @diffusion.email.size
  end
end
```